# az login fails in automated jenkinsscript

Tags: jenkins, azure-cli

I am having a script in a Jenkins Pipeline, which is trying to login into azure using the azure cli. The command is getting executed inside a simple container, which is defined like:

```
FROM microsoft/azure-cli:latest

RUN az acs kubernetes install-cli
```

and the command which is runs is:

```
az login -u **** -p ****
```

Before today this approach worked pretty well and also if I run the command locally on my machine it seems to work, but since today I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: WS-Trust RST request returned http error: 503
```

Any idea what I can do to prevent that ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I changed nothing, but today everything worked again.